Возможно ли написать "не реален" раздельно в предложении?
"Потому что я не реален. Всё это время я был лишь плодом твоего воображения."
Спасибо.
(Завязался спор, в процессе которого я настаивал на слитном написании слова, поскольку не видел противопоставления либо усиления отрицания.)

Добавлю ответ Грамоты, после которого понятнее не стало.
https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/320254
Хотелось бы ответ на вопрос -- почему так, а не иначе?

Вот после этого ответа я и пришёл сюда, поскольку здесь люди более развёрнуто отвечают.

Потому что я (не) реален. Всё это время я был лишь плодом твоего воображения.

Решение зависит от контекста. Дело в том, то возможны обе формы: нереален как утверждение и не реален как отрицание. Это видно из толкового словаря.

Грамота дает вариант с отрицанием, при этом ориентируется на противопоставление: я не реальный, а воображаемый. Такой вариант сразу видится по тексту. Но все же возможно разное толкование.


Вариант 1. Я не реален (отрицание)
Ты неверно меня представляешь.  Потому что я не реален (а фантастичен). Всё это время я был лишь плодом твоего воображения.
Вариант 2. Я нереален (утверждение)
Ты неверно меня представляешь. Потому что я нереален (= фантастичен). Всё это время я был лишь плодом твоего воображения.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
НЕРЕАЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. 1. Не существующий 
в действительности; воображаемый. Гомеровскую Трою долго 
считали нереальной. // Непохожий на действительность; 
фантастический, сказочный. Сюжет фильма был нереальным. Н-ые 
лунные пейзажи. 

РЕАЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. 1. Существующий на 
самом деле, действительный, не воображаемый. Р. мир. Р-ая 
действительность. Р-ая основа бытия. Р-ая жизнь. Р-ая 
заработная плата (покупательная способность заработной 
платы).


Речь о друге, который притворяется воображаемым.
https://pikabu.ru/story/spryachus_12134911?utm_source=andpostshare&utm_medium=sharing
